# Cypress Joomla installation test fails

Tags: cms-testing, cypress

So locally I'm working fine with cypress tests for my Joomla Component.
When I try to test the Joomla installation in my repository on GitHub something is wrong.

My cypress config is similar to this one:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/5.0-dev/cypress.config.dist.js

and I use the same installation test that Joomla uses:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/5.0-dev/tests/System/integration/install/Installation.cy.js

using these Helpers:
https://github.com/joomla-projects/joomla-cypress

The problem I have is that the `installJoomla` function from this helper:
https://github.com/joomla-projects/joomla-cypress/blob/develop/src/joomla.js

is not deleting the installation folder like the `installJoomlaMultilingualSite` does.

So this always fails because the installation folder is still there:

```
cy.installJoomla(config);
cy.doAdministratorLogin(config.username, config.password, false); // fails
```

Am I missing something here?